# build fails because of unused imported package in the class

Tags: java, import, build, compilation

I have one query that in my Java class. Let's say I have imported a package which
was not at all going to be used in the class at all, so eclipse editor give me the warning
to remove that unused import package, which is fine enough but still let's say I have not remove that unused package.

Now, when I am going to run the build of my project, it is not compiling successfully
since it is throwing an exception indicating the error towards that unused imported package.
The point of worry is: Why does the build fail because of that unimported package?

The point is that build should be faild in eclipse itself and compile time exception should be shown.

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message. Tell us how you build that project.

Comment: Whether you use it or not, your code refers to it via the import statement. If you're getting a compile error, it's because the project cannot find the library you've imported. Comment out the import or provide the library. (better?)

Comment: Eclipse IDE uses an incremental compiler and inetllisense to figure out that imports are (not) being used really and it just gives you warning. However, a command line tool like javac from standard JDK (you have not mentioned what tool and compiler is being used for build) will first try to resolve all the imports from the class path and then only proceed to generate byte codes. In your case even imports are unused compiler is trying to reolve/load those classes and failing. It does not look ahead and checks if these are really being used or not.